# Real time updates from Rails app to Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, real-time, channel, channel-api

I need to have real time updates from one Rails app to another.

One Rails app of mine runs in a restaurant, in a local environment, but is connected to the internet.

Another Rails app is a public web app hosted in DigitalOcean.

When an order is received in the public server, regarding a specific restaurant, for example "Restaurant X", I want to push data, for example "1 tortilla and 1 pepsi" to Restaurant X's local server. And vice versa. An order received in Restaurant X should be immediately published to the public server.

The way I currently implement this, is by having every restaurant (Restaurant X, Restaurant Y and Restaurant Z) polling the public server every 20 seconds, but I wanted to publish changes automatically.

Rails has a Channels functionality to aid in real-time updates, but the [examples](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) are only based on Rails app publishing to Javascript-based clients. I wanted the restaurants's servers to be the clients. Meaning, a Rails app publishing to clients that are another Rails apps, 1 room per restaurant. How could I accomplish that, please?

Comment: channels are limited to server/browser configurations, not server/server. You can post to the restaurant servers, but they would need to have urls, so they cannot run in local environments. Polling is your best option, unless you make your restaurant servers accessible with urls. They don't need to have domain names, IP addresses would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of polling, you're looking for the pub/sub design pattern. Here's a nice tutorial: https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/the-publish-subscribe-pattern-on-rails